# Using tensorflow model maker how to save checkpoints during training

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am using the [TensorflowLite model maker](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/modify/model_maker) and I would like to know how I can during training regularily save checkpoints so I can check the loss graphs with tensorboard. How is this done?

This function I call when I want to train but there seems to be no argument for additional settings like writing checkpoints or specifying a directory for it.

`model = object_detector.create(train_data, model_spec=spec, batch_size=8, train_whole_model=True, validation_data=validation_data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found out how it works! The param `grad_checkpoint=true` has to set in the spec object that is given to the object_detector.create() function! In the spec the model checkpoint dir can also be specified!
This is how I got it working:

```
spec = object_detector.EfficientDetLite0Spec(
    model_name='efficientdet-lite0',
    model_dir='/home/alex/checkpoints_1/',
    hparams='grad_checkpoint=true,strategy=gpus',
    epochs=30, batch_size=8,
    steps_per_execution=1, moving_average_decay=0,
    var_freeze_expr='(efficientnet|fpn_cells|resample_p6)',
    tflite_max_detections=25
)

model = object_detector.create(train_data, model_spec=spec, batch_size=8, 
    train_whole_model=True, validation_data=validation_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow Lite Model Maker doesn't provide a direct way to save checkpoints during training, but you can use [tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard?hl=it). Try the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf

checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath='path/to/checkpoints/model_checkpoint.h5',
    save_weights_only=True,
    save_best_only=True,
    monitor='val_loss',  # Choose a metric to monitor
    mode='min',  # 'min' or 'max' depending on the metric
)

tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(
    log_dir='path/to/tensorboard/logs',
    write_graph=True,
    write_images=True
)

# Train the model with callbacks
model.fit(
    train_data,
    validation_data=validation_data,
    epochs=10,  # Set the number of epochs
    callbacks=[checkpoint_callback, tensorboard_callback]
)
```

let me know if you need more info about tensorboard

Comment: Hi Marco, yes I know how to use this when I use normal tensorflow. I was wondering how I can do this when running the line above using TFLite Model Maker. But I have just found a way to do it! I will post it as answer!

Comment: ah okei! Great ;)